# WHERE clause where value is convertible

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, type-conversion

Is there a way in `SQL Server` using `T-SQL` to say:

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, mat1_04_05, 101) = true
```

I'm doing some reporting against an app that I don't have source for and the column is `varchar` and I can't rely on user data.

*EDIT*

I tried using `ISDATE`. However I'm still running into a conversion error this is the full query:

```
SELECT mat1_04_01                                    AS 'CaseStg',
       matter.mat_no                                 AS 'MatNo',
       MAX(matter.client)                            AS 'Client',
       MAX(mat1_03_01)                               AS 'InCo',
       MAX(mat1_07_01)                               AS 'Clm Amt',
       MAX(mat1_07_03)                               AS 'Clm Bal',
       MAX(mat1_04_05)                               AS 'BilSnt',
       MAX(mat1_01_07)                               AS 'Injured',
       CONVERT(CHAR, MIN(CONVERT(DATE, usr1_02_01))) AS dos_start,
       CONVERT(CHAR, MAX(CONVERT(DATE, usr1_02_02))) AS dos_end
FROM   lntmuser.matter
       INNER JOIN lntmuser.usertype1
         ON lntmuser.matter.sysid = lntmuser.usertype1.mat_id
WHERE  Isdate(mat1_04_05) = 1
       AND Datediff(DAY, CONVERT(DATE, mat1_04_05, 101), Getdate()) > 31
       AND mat1_04_01 LIKE 'BILLING MAILED OUT'
       AND matter.status NOT LIKE 'CLOSED'
GROUP  BY mat1_04_01,
          matter.mat_no
```

Comment: What do you mean by true?  Are you checking if it's in a certain format, or are you checking if it exists?

Comment: I'm trying to run a report and disregard / find the data entry that retards fluck up and developer didn't handle lol.

Comment: @Adrain thank you I was just trying to straighten that up

Comment: Dude -- it doesn't make sense to use ISDATE() and CONVERT() on the same date field without a control structure...see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude -- it doesn't make sense to use `ISDATE()` and `CONVERT()` on the same date field in your WHERE without a control structure.  I.e., if `ISDATE()` = false, then `CONVERT()` is guaranteed to give you a conversion error.

Try this:

```
WHERE
...
CASE WHEN ISDATE(myDateField) = 1 THEN DATEDIFF(CONVERT(...)) ELSE 0 END > 31
```

Answer (score 1):

DO you mean check to see whether that column is a date??

```
WHERE ISDATE(matl_04_05) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ISDATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx).

```
... WHERE ISDATE(mat1_04_05) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understood your original question...

```
IF ISDATE('2009-05-12 10:19:41.177') = 1
    PRINT 'VALID'
ELSE
    PRINT 'INVALID'
```

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like

```
SELECT * FROM FOO where ISDATE(mat1_04_05)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `datetime` you can;

```
;with T(F) as (
    select 'cake' union
    select '01 mar 2011'
)
select cast(f as datetime) from T where isdate(F) = 1

>>F
>>2011-03-01 00:00:00.000
```