# Using case statements with IsDate in a SQL where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to clean up the where clause statement in the following code:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(datetime, [UTC_Time_Stamp], 127) AS TimeStamp
FROM 
    Table 
WHERE 
    CASE 
       WHEN ISDATE([UTC_Time_Stamp]) = 1 
       THEN CONVERT(datetime, [UTC_Time_Stamp], 127) 
       ELSE CAST('1/1/1900' AS datetime) 
    END > CAST('11/09/2012' AS datetime) 
    AND 
       CASE 
          WHEN ISDATE([UTC_Time_Stamp]) = 1 
          THEN CONVERT(datetime, [UTC_Time_Stamp], 127) 
          ELSE CAST('1/1/3000' AS datetime) 
       END < CAST('11/10/2012' as datetime) 
ORDER BY 
    TimeStamp;
```

`UTC_Time_Stamp` is stored as a string and is sometimes null. I was previously running into a conversion error inside my where clause. I fixed the error following advice from this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944116/sql-server-where-clause-where-value-is-convertible), but I feel like there has to be a simpler way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Is that the 11th of September or the 9th of November....

Comment: 9th of November (mm/dd/yyyy).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *need* to do the conversion within a `case` statement.  SQL is a descriptive language and does not guarantee the order of processing.  So, a `where` clause does not necessarily happen before other processing, even when it is in a subquery or a CTE.  However, SQL does guarantee the order of processing in a `case` statement (that contains no expressions with aggregation functions).

You can simplify your statement by using a subquery:

```
select TimeStamp
FROM (select t.*,
             Case When ISDATE([UTC_Time_Stamp]) = 1 Then CONVERT(datetime, UTC_Time_Stamp, 127) end) as TimeStamp
      from Table t
     ) t
WHERE coalesce(TimeStamp, cast('1/1/1900' as datetime)) > cast('11/09/2012' as datetime) and
      coalesce(TimeStamp, cast('1/1/3000' as datetime)) < cast('11/10/2012' as datetime) 
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```

This does the conversion to TimeStamp, for valid values.  You can then use the variable in the outer query.

I would also encourage you to get used to the ANSI standard format for dates (YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD) instead of ambiguous formats like '11/10/2012'.  It may be clear to you that this means 2012-11-10 . . . or is that 2012-10-11 . . . but the format is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

I like CTEs for this, or you could also do temp tables, table variables or an inline derived table like @Derek.

Basically, we're going to grab the proper datatype first, and then have a much easier time creating our query:

```
;with CTE as (
    -- Bring back the column as datetime
    select case when isdate(UTC_Time_Stamp) = 1 then cast(UTC_Time_Stamp as datetime) end as UTC_Time_Stamp
    from [Table]
)
-- Simple select with the proper datatype
select convert(varchar(50), UTC_Time_Stamp, 127) as [TimeStamp]
from CTE
-- May still need gt and lt functionality
where UTC_Time_Stamp between cast('11/09/2012' as datetime) and cast('11/10/2012' as datetime)
```

It seems like you're using some arbitrarily small and large values for TimeStamp when you have non-dates, which is probably unnecessary given your comparison, so I've removed them.

Note that I am using the datetime datatype in the CTE and for the comparison, only converting it to a string for presentation.

Also note that `between` is inclusive, so you might need to go back to your separate `>` and `<` where clause.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do something like this (using whatever convert/between clause in the predicate that you see fit):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, [UTC_Time_Stamp], 127) as TimeStamp
FROM (
  select [UTC_Time_Stamp] 
  from Table 
  WHERE ISDATE([UTC_Time_Stamp]) = 1 
) a
WHERE
  convert(datetime, [UTC_Time_Stamp], 127) between '11/9/2012' and '11/10/2012'
ORDER BY TimeStamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this time for me this solves the problem of working with temporary table alias 
or sub queries that can slow down the selection of millions of records.

```
select your_column 
from your_table 
where case when ISDATE(your_column) = 1 
           then Cast(your_column as date) 
      end Between '01/01/2016' and '01/01/2017' 
order by your_column
```

Regards