# TSQL that works normally but not through sp_executesql

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime

I have some C# code that looks like this:

```
string strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT A." + strProcessingDateColumn
        + " FROM GA_Item A "
        + " WHERE A.TOWControlID = @TOWControlID"
        + " AND A.ItemTypeExt = 'PDF' "
        + " AND A." + strSourceColumn + " = 'Teller Report' "
        + " AND A." + strReportNumberColumn + " = @ReportNum "
        + " AND A." + strIBTColumn + " <> '9999' "
        + " AND ISNULL(A." + strMergedColumn + ", 'N') = 'N'"
        + " AND CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A." + strProcessingDateColumn + ")) AS DATETIME) < @ProcessingDate";
      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strSql, conn))
      {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOWControlID", iTOWControlID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReportNum", iReportNumber.ToString());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessingDate", dtCurrentDate);
        try
        {
          using (SqlDataReader datereader = command.ExecuteReader())
          {
            while (datereader.Read())
            {
              //...
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Which generates an sp_executesql statement (which I pulled from the SQL profiler) that looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT DISTINCT A.UserField1 FROM GA_Item A
WHERE A.TOWControlID = @TOWControlID
    AND A.ItemTypeExt = ''PDF''
    AND A.UserField4 = ''Teller Report''
    AND A.UserField3 = @ReportNum
    AND A.UserField2 <> ''9999''
    AND ISNULL(A.UserField5, ''N'') = ''N''
    AND CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1)) AS DATETIME) < @ProcessingDate'
,N'@TOWControlID int,@ReportNum nvarchar(1),@ProcessingDate datetime'
,@TOWControlID=9999
,@ReportNum=N'6'
,@ProcessingDate='2015-03-24 00:00:00'
```

Which results in 2 errors: `The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.` and `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

That leads me to believe that something is causing an overflow in the table I'm selecting from. However, if I extract the query out of the sp_executesql statement so it looks like this:

```
declare @TOWControlID int = 9999,
        @ReportNum nvarchar = '6',
        @ProcessingDate datetime = '2015-03-24'
SELECT DISTINCT A.UserField1 FROM GA_Item A
WHERE A.TOWControlID = @TOWControlID
      AND A.ItemTypeExt = 'PDF'
      AND A.UserField4 = 'Teller Report'
      AND A.UserField3 = @ReportNum
      AND A.UserField2 <> '9999'
      AND ISNULL(A.UserField5, 'N') = 'N'
      AND CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1 AS DATETIME))) < @ProcessingDate
```

The query works as expected.

The stranger thing is that this exact code used to work in SQL 2000, but we have migrated the system to use SQL 2008 and now we are getting this problem. I had an issue in SQL 2000 where the query straight up refused to run unless the datetime equality condition was the last one in the list, so once we moved it to the bottom of the list it worked fine for months.

I have checked and double checked and I cannot see anything wrong with the data I'm giving it, as well as the data in the table. I can convert every value in UserField1 (which is an `nvarchar(256)`) to a datetime no problem in a separate query.

Am I missing something?

The schema of the table is quite large, so I won't post the whole thing here, but it basically boils down to `UserField1-20 nvarchar(256), null`, `TOWControlID int null`, and `ItemTypeEXT nvarchar(50), null`

I should also note that if I remove the `AND CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1)) AS DATETIME) < @ProcessingDate` from the sp_executesql statement the query runs, but it doesn't get the right results.

Everything is pointing to a data error in the table, but if I run this:

```
declare @TOWControlID int = 9999,
        @ReportNum nvarchar = '6',
        @ProcessingDate datetime = '2015-03-24'
SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1)) FROM GA_Item A
WHERE A.TOWControlID = @TOWControlID
      AND A.ItemTypeExt = 'PDF'
      AND A.UserField4 = 'Teller Report'
      AND A.UserField3 = @ReportNum
      AND A.UserField2 <> '9999'
      AND ISNULL(A.UserField5, 'N') = 'N'
```

The query executes fine.

Comment: Can you show us the table definition?

Comment: @RBarryYoung See my update. The table is huge, so I only posted the relevant ones.

Comment: Look at the values for "A.UserField1" ... that looks to be the problem.  Do you have any null, empty-string, or non-date-time formatted values in that column?

Comment: Does sp_executesql work if you specify @ProcessingDate='24 March 2015'

Comment: Do a "SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1)) AS DATETIME) FROM GA_Item A" and see if you get the error.  If so, the problem is a data problem in that table.

Comment: @pmbAustin it falls over with other data that falls outside of the criteria I specify, because it's a dynamic table that has a separate `TableDefinitions` table. If I use the same criteria as in my query, except for the datetime bit, it works fine.

Comment: try using the isdate function to check the field before conversion https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx

Comment: @Ewan I tried `select distinct isdate(a.Userfield1)`... and everything is a valid date apparently.

Comment: try changing ,@ProcessingDate='2015-03-24 00:00:00' in the sp_execute to ,@ProcessingDate='20150324'

Comment: @Ewan that didn't work either :(

Comment: To determine if it is the parameter being read wrong or the column (even though you tested the column already, but bear with me), try adding `, @ProcessingDate, CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1)) AS DATETIME)` to your select statement and remove the where clause containing them. Let it run, if you get an error, remove one and try again, repeat reverse and you should be able to know which one is giving the actual problem

Comment: @BerndLinde it works with both of them... what the hell?

Comment: try my answer, (and the other suggestions) but do it in the code, not sql manager. it could be that some things work in that but not in code and vice versa

Comment: also msdn is saying use convert instead of cast

Comment: Convert has the same issue.

Comment: Have you manually ran the entire `sp_executesql` command with the same result?

Comment: just reading that the order of the where clause isn't guarenteed. so you have to explicity exclude the non dates in a subselect or case statement before you do your comparisom. this would explain why one way of executing works while the other dosnt. and you problem with it having to be the last where clause in 2008

Comment: @BerndLinde all changes I've tried so far have been in the entire sp_executesql command.

Comment: that's a good thing as you expect the query to work when the dates are correctly excuded. I think youll find my solution works if you put it in the code

Comment: @Ewan I'm trying it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do a subselect to get the converted date, or an error date if it can't convert and then compare against that

```
CASE 
WHEN ISDATE(LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1))) = 1 
THEN CONVERT(datetime, LTRIM(RTRIM(A.UserField1))) 
ELSE @ProcessingDate END as convertedDate

and convertedDate < @ProcessingDate
```

it seems the where clause evaluation order is not specified. so non dates which should be excluded by the other clauses, may be evaluated as dates unless the excusion clause happens to run first

[Using case statements with IsDate in a SQL where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13347582/using-case-statements-with-isdate-in-a-sql-where-clause)

Comment: I will as soon as I've put it in the code and confirmed it is working. I tried it in management studio and it was happy in that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the date format explicitly, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Did the default language change after the upgrade to SQL2008, see

[How to change the language and date format in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220023/how-to-change-the-language-and-date-format-in-sql-server)

Comment: How do I do that with a parameterized query?

Comment: You need to make the change in the C# code to send the date in the format that SQL expects (03-24-2015...) or change the dateformat option in the database to ymd instead of mdy which is the default (dbcc useroptions -> dateformat)